# What is the full form of an expressionless statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There's a syntax that Javascript adopted from C where you can perform a logical check, without checking anything:

```
if (foo) { 
}
```

What is this equivalent to? Is it:

```
if (foo != null) { }
if (foo !== null) { }
if (typeof(foo) != 'undefined') { }
if (typeof(foo) !== 'undefined') { }
if (typeof(foo) != 'object') { }
if (typeof(foo) !== 'Object') { }
```

My actual motivation for asking is wanting to ensure that a member *"exists"* (that is to say, if it is `null` or `undefined` then it doesn't exist):

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio !== null)
if (window.devicePixelRatio != null)
if (!(window.devicePixelRatio == null))
if (!(window.devicePixelRatio === null))
if (!(window.devicePixelRatio == undefined))
if (!(window.devicePixelRatio === undefined))
if ((window.devicePixelRatio !== undefined))
```

My concern is if the member is *defined*, but defined to be `null`, in which case (as far as i'm concerned) it's not assigned.

I know that the expressionless syntax returns `true` for a *"truthy"* value. I'm less interested in a *"truthy"* value, as an actual value.

Comment: Note that foo also returns false if it is defined and equal to `0`.

Comment: @Cristy In which case it is a valid value :)

Comment: @IanBoyd, it is valid but the `if` is not executed. `var foo = 0; if(foo) console.log(1)` will output nothing, so it is not equivalent with any of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> if (foo) { 
> }
> ```
>
> *"What is this equivalent to?"*

It's not equivalent to any of the ones you suggested. It would be equivalent to:

```
if (Boolean(foo)) { }
```

or the same thing by using the `!` operator:

```
if (!!foo) { }
```

or you could be explicit in your comparison if you really want.

```
if (!!foo === true) { }
```

---

> *"My actual motivation for asking is wanting to ensure that a member "exists"..."*

To find if a member exists in an object, use the `in` operator.

```
if ("devicePixelRatio" in window) { }
```

---

> *"... (that is to say, if it is null or undefined then it doesn't exist):"*

To check for not `null` or `undefined`, which is no the same as not existing, do this:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio != null) { }
```

The `!=` operator will perform both a `null` and `undefined` check at the same time. Any other value will meet the condition.

Comment: And we just got through being told that [`!=` should not be used](http://www.jshint.com/). *Le sigh*

Comment: @IanBoyd: Yeah, just like any feature, one should understand how it works and use it when appropriate. The semantics of `==` and `!=` can be a little confusing, but this is one particular case where it's very simple and helpful. Nothing is `== null` or `== undefined` except for `null` and `undefined`. You can configure jsHint to turn off that warning.